# How to format custom token for Firestore authentication?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, access-token

I have the following methods that I use to log in with Google -

```kotlin
override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        when (view?.id) {
           ...


            R.id.google_login -> {
                val signInIntent: Intent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE)
            }
        }
    }



override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK || requestCode != GOOGLE_LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE) return
        val task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount> = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
        val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
        saveAccountData(account)
    }

    private fun saveAccountData(account: GoogleSignInAccount?) {
        if (account == null) {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), getString(R.string.login_fragment_null_account_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }
        if (account.email == null) {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), getString(R.string.login_fragment_selected_account_has_no_email_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return
        }
        // This method saves the data in my Firestore DB 
        viewmodel.registerUser(account).observeOnce(requireActivity(), Observer { error ->
            error?.let { message ->
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@Observer
            }

            saveAccountToPrefs(account)

            navController.navigate(LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToTermsAndConditionsFragment(account.givenName!!))
        })
    }

private fun saveAccountToPrefs(account: GoogleSignInAccount) {
        profileSharedPrefs.edit {
            putString(USER_REGISTERED_ID, account.email)
            putString(USER_DISPLAY_NAME, account.displayName)
            putString(USER_TOKEN, account.id)
            putBoolean(DID_USER_REGISTER, true)
        }
    }
```

The issue is that, I have the following bad rules for my database -

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
    
      allow read, write: if true
    }
  }
}
```

and I want to add simple authentication like the following -

```
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

So, when trying to configure a custom token like here when I am using the ID (which is an email of the user) I always get an error -

```kotlin
private fun authAndNavigate(directions : NavDirections) {
        auth.signInWithCustomToken(profileSharedPrefs.getString(USER_TOKEN, "")!!)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), auth.currentUser.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    navController.navigate(directions)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Authentication failed, please restart app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    return@addOnCompleteListener
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                exception.localizedMessage?.let { message ->
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
    }
```

The error I get is -

> The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation. [ Invalid assertion format. 3 dot-separated segments required. ]

I could not find any example of how to actually format my ID (which is an email) in a way that would first work and not throw an error and secondly work with the rules I want to implement into my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get back from Google sign-in is an OAuth credential, which you can use to sign in with Firebase by passing those credentials to `signInWithCredential` as shown in step 4 in this documentation on [signing in with Firebase with Google auth credentials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin#authenticate_with_firebase).

Your code calls `signInWithCustomToken`, which expects a custom JWT as minted by code you'd run on your own trusted environment as shown in the documentation on [minting custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).

While both types of tokens can be used to authenticate with Firebase, you can't interchange them in API calls.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried what you said and the issue is that I get `idToken` as null always and I do get `id` but trying to use it as credential gives me an error - `the supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired`. Am I missing anything?

Comment: found the answer alone, but thanks for the general direction. my issue is solved.